Decoding Raydium AMM program transaction instructions in Rust
I'm working on listening for events on Raydium v4 AMM program and have figured out most of what I need. However, I'm currently stuck on decoding Raydium transaction instructions. Has anyone done something similar or know a good approach for this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Not really, also i'm looking for something in RUST, I'm already familiar with how to do it in Typescript
